# How to store array of numpy array in csv file?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, csv, encoding

I have an image name, image path and it's corresponding cnn feature vector (a numpy array). And there are many images, meaning I have a list of names, paths, vectors (each being numpy array of dimension (1, 2048, 14, 14) and float32 as data type). I have to store and access in an efficient way. I was thinking of going with storing it in a csv file. When I did that, I am unable to convert back the numpy array from str. Kindly let me know how to proceed with this, thank you.

```py
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name', 'path', 'vector'])
data['name'] = image_names
data['path'] = image_paths
for i in range(len(image_paths)):
   out = encoder(image_paths[i] #(1,2048,14,14)
   data['vector'][i] = out
data.to_csv('encoding.csv', sep = ',', na_rep='Unknown')
```

```py
dr =pd.read_csv('encoding.csv')
for i in range(dr.shape[0]):
    c = dr['vector'][i]
```

c is a str object. Unsure how to convert this to numpy array.

Comment: `csv` even when it works is not an 'efficient way'.  It is text, designed primarily to save numbers and strings, laid out in a table, much like a spread sheet..  A simple 2d numeric dtype array can be saved nicely with `np.savetxt`, and loaded with `np.loadtxt`.  But without knowing how you saved the file, or at least seeing a sample of the file, we cannot help you recover the data.

Comment: " I have to store and access in an efficient way. I was thinking of going with storing it in a csv file." csv is the *last* thing you should think of if you want an "efficient way".

Comment: Hi, I created a pandas dataframe and I stored the image_path, image_name, cnn_vector in csv. When I read the csv file, all are str objects. Here, the name and path are string itself, so there was no need for conversion but my numpy array is 'str' object now and I wasn't able to convert it back with json.loads() or common methods which I came across. Hence, I posted this question.

Comment: @KaladharshiniK you *really* need to provide a [mcve]. While prose descriptions are good to have, they are not replacements for *code* that provides *precise* examples

Comment: @KaladharshiniK of course not, `json.loads` is for parsing JSON, just dumping the string representation of a `numpy.ndarray` object will not create json, and indeed, is not meant to be used as a serialization technique. Those are *hacks* that are used to recover data when someone has fundamentally made a mistake. You should probably be using `pickle`, which would be the easiest way to solve this problem.

Comment: So just use `pickle` to save and reload your data. It will use `numpy.save` underneath the hood to serialize the `numpy.ndarray` objects

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga
Thank you so much, I learnt a lot with your comments. I also changed the way that I was saving. Used `np.save` and `np.load` as suggested below.

Comment: look at the vector column of the csv -'encoding.csv'  .  Given the 2d nature of csv, it can only write a string representation of the array elements.  And load it as strings as well.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, I understand its working now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save the numpy array using `numpy.save` as shown in the [docs here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html). You could save the image name and image path as a `.json` file (and just make the name of the `.npy` file the same as the name as the `.json` file to allow for easier searching).